# How to handle redirect website in WebKit

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, redirect, wkwebview

I need to recognise redirection url address in `WKWebView`.

On start in `viewDidLoad` I create request and load it into `webView`. It looks like this:

```
let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: https://example.com/)!)
webView.navigationDelegate = self
webView.load(request)
```

then website in `webView`redirect me to another website, for example `https://www.NEWSITE.com` 
How can I recognise / handle this redirection and print this new url address in my app? Any suggestions?

> UPDATE:  Solution in delegate method

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    print(navigationAction.request.url)
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

Comment: 'It looks like that:'  Am I missing something?  Looks like what?

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: @piterpan : You have posted the answer as a part of your question itself. decidePolicyFor navigationAction is where you get t know the url being loaded if you want it to load run decisionHandler will allow else run with deny thats all

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I know :) I found a solution and posted it

Comment: @piterpan : Thats great buddy that you figured out the solution on your own :) But you should add that as a answer to your question and accept it. That way it will help somebody who stumbles upon the same problem if you modify the question itself and add it as answer its little confusing :) Add it as answer community members will appreciate it as well on the other hand if its a duplicate question I mean you found solution for it somewhere else on SO you can delete the question duplicate questions wont help community much